# Calculating derived value in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, dstream

I have two Key Value Pairs of the type org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[Int].

First Key value pair is (word,frequency). 
Second key value pair is (Number of rows,Value).

I would like to divide frequency by value in for each word. But, I am getting below error
 *value / is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[Int]*

Sample Code :

f is frequency of the word and c is the total count
rdd has word and frequency

```
val cp = rdd.foreachRDD {
  x => (x, f/c)
}
```

Comment: is f is the object of DStream?

Answer (score 0):

First apply map transformation on the DStream object and then inside that you will get RDD now you apply map transformation on RDD object as follow

```
dStream.map{rdd=>
 rdd.map(x=>(x,f/c))
}
```

if f is the object of DStream then collect it first before use it in RDD or DStream closure.

Comment: Yes F is an object of Dstream. But when I try to collect it says value collect is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[Int]

Comment: I m not suggested this as a good solution but one thing you can do you cab save f DStream in file with saveAsTextFiles action and then read that text file as RDD and collect it n then use that  as value of f